# What is the standard way to set default paths for function arguments in R packages?

Tags: r, function, r-package, default-arguments

Setting default values for R functions is straightforward, e.g.

```
myfunction = function(x, k=42, c=1){
    result = x*x + k - c
    return(result)
}
```

Here, by default `k=42`, `c=1`, and `x` is a required argument.

I'm creating an R package whereby I would like the arguments to be default files. (In this case, these could either be variables loaded via `.rda` files, or actual text or csv files.)

To provide the path to a file in `inst/extdata`, the documentation recommends using the following:

http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html

> For example, to find inst/extdata/mydata.csv, you’d call
>   system.file("extdata", "mydata.csv", package = "mypackage")

What is the recommended way to create function arguments which default to a certain file?

I think directly linking to the files would be not the best approach, e.g.

```
do_something_with_data = function(file=system.file("extdata", "mydata.csv", package = "mypackage")){
    data.table::fread(file)
    ...
}
```

Another approach could be to set all such arguments to `NULL`, and then use the default arguments if nothing else is used:

```
do_something_with_data2 = function(file=NULL){
    if (is.null(file)){
        file = system.file("extdata", "mydata.csv", package = "mypackage")
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you think what you call "directly linking to the files" would be a bad idea?  It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @user2554330 Is directly linking to the files the correct standard? If so, please answer. I don't know, so I am asking.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard:  R is flexible, and different people do things in different ways.  But I would usually choose your first solution instead of the second one, because it makes documentation easier:  the default shows up in the header of the function.

Comment: @user2554330 I understand your point with regards to documentation, but the developer could always be thorough in the roxygen2 comments.

Comment: I liked `roxygen2`-like systems 25 years ago (not for R!), but I don't use it now.  I think the Rd files, with support from RStudio, make it easier to write good docs.  But I wouldn't forsake the automatic documentation you get from putting your intentions into the function header.